# Get unique occurancies from array by last 3 letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there some efficient way to get all occurancies of field value in array of hashes with same three last letters ?

I have an array like this:

```
array = [
    {
        :code => 'R01L01'
    },
    {
        :code => 'R02ZZZ'
    },
    {
        :code => 'A03ZZZ'
    },
    {
        :code => 'A04L01'
    },
    {
        :code => 'D11ZZZ'
    },
    {
        :code => 'D22DAR'
    },
]
```

In response i want to have R01L01, R02ZZZ, D22DAR so i will have unique codes by last three letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array.
  flat_map(&:values).
  group_by { |e| e[/.{3}\z/] }. # or e[-3..-1], see comments
  map { |_, v| v.first }
#⇒ ["R01L01", "R02ZZZ", "D22DAR"]
```

Comment: How about `e[-3, 3]` or `e[-3..-1]`?

Comment: Disregard please.